# Why do I need brackets around lambda functions when assigning them to variables?

Tags: python, lambda

I've just stumbled about some unexpected behavior in Python in the below code snippet

```
b = False

func_1 = lambda x,y:set([x]) == y if b else lambda x,y: x in y
func_2 = None   

if not b:
    func_2 = lambda x,y : x in y
else:
    func_2 = lambda x,y:set([x]) == y 

print(func_1("Hello", set(["Hello", "World"])))
print(func_2("Hello", set(["Hello", "World"])))
```

The output is

```
<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f7e5eeed048>
True
```

However, when adding brackets around the lambdas everything works as expected:

```
func_1 = (lambda x,y:set([x]) == y) if b else (lambda x,y: x in y)
# ...
```

The output then is

```
True
True
```

Why do I need those brackets? I thought the initial expression was equivalent to the long if-else construct.

Comment: I think the answer is in the `if else` part more than the `lambda`

Comment: You only need the bracket on the first lambda. You need to tell the parser where to stop otherwise it tries to include the 'if' statement

Comment: When in doubt about operator precedence, use brackets (or look it up, but brackets are faster). I didn't know the precedence of `lambda` w.r.t. `if` before reading this, and I'll probably have forgotten by next week. But I'm fairly certain I'd have used brackets if I'd written that code, just to be safe!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just standard precedence rules. Your first expression is being parsed as:

```
lambda x,y:set([x]) == (y if b else lambda x,y: x in y)
```

So you need to add the parentheses to create the correct precedence.

Comment: This rule is not very intuitive. Now, I understand why my program did not work...Thanks